# Using Solve for Objective function max/min

Tags: mathematical-optimization, inequalities

I have an objective function

```
z = 4 x + 2 y
```

with constraints of

```
x + 2 y >= 4 && 3 x + y >= 7 && -x + 2 y <= 7 && x >= 0 && y >= 0
```

(Answer for this particular set of constraints should show a minimum of 10 and no maximum value or that the max is a function `z = 4 x`, either are fine.)

I tried using `Solve` :

```
Solve[z == 4 x + 2 y && x + 2 y >= 4 && 3 x + y >= 7 && -x + 2 y <= 7 && x >= 0 && y >= 0, Reals]
```

which outputs:

```
  Out[2]= {{x -> ConditionalExpression[1/4 (-2 y + z), 
          (10 < z <= 12 && 28 + 2 y - 3 z <= 0 && -16 + 6 y + z >= 0) || 
          (12 < z <= 16 && -16 + 6 y + z >= 0 && -28 + 10 y - z <= 0) || 
          (z > 16 && -28 + 10 y - z <= 0 && y >= 0)]},
          {x -> 2, y -> 1, z -> 10}}
```

This is fine and dandy for the particular example since the second part has the minimum value I was looking for, but for my application, the coefficients will be able to be changed by the user.  While testing it, sometimes `Solve` only had the `ConditionalExpression` when I expected it to show the z minimum value similar to the above output.

So my question is this. Am I using `Solve` incorrectly and I'm just missing something, or is there a different function that would be more suitable for me to use to get a minimum and/or maximum value for z?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Minimize. It will give you the analytical solution:

```
Minimize[{4 x + 2 y, 
  x + 2 y >= 4 && 3 x + y >= 7 && -x + 2 y <= 7 && x >= 0 && 
   y >= 0}, {x, y}]
```

Output:

```
{10,{x->2,y->1}}
```

For Problems that require heuristical optimization or can't be solved analytically, use FindMinimum

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I have to check both max and min, so for `Maximize`, I had to wrap with `Quiet` since there's an error when it is unbounded.